# How to send request through websocket while recieving responses

Tags: python, json, websocket

I'm working on a project that involves sending requests and getting responses from an API through a web socket. When I send the "subscribe" request to the API, the API will continuously send responses through the web socket and I need to call websocket.recv() in a loop to listen to the responses. How can I send the "unsubscribe" command to terminate the subscription while listening to the responses?

```
...
ws = websocket.create_connection(url, sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
while True:
 command = input('> ')
 if command == 'subscribe':
    try:
        request = {
            "id": 1,
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "subscribe",
            "params": {
                "token": token,
                "session": session_id,
            }
        }
        ws.send(json.dumps(request))
        while True:          #I think it should be something else instead of while true     
          result = ws.recv()
          result = json.loads(result)
          print(result)
    except:
        print('No existing token or session')
 elif command == 'unsubscribe':
    try:
        request = {
            "id": 2,
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "unsubscribe",
            "params": {
                "token": token,
                "session": session_id,
            }
        }
        ws.send(json.dumps(request))
    except:
        print('No existing token or session')
...
```

Do I have to use multithreading? Is there a better way to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the list to_send contains the messages you want to send during the recv().
What you should do is use socket.settimeout() and set it to something low (let's say 0.01 seconds), and use it in a loop. that way, every 0.01 you can take a pause from receiving, send whatever is in to_send, and then continue receiving new messages.

code example:

```
    your_socket = socket.socket()
    to_send = []
    received_messages = []
    stop = False

    your_socket.settimeout(0.01)
    while not stop:
        try:
            msg = your_socket.recv(1024)
            received_messages.append(msg)
        except socket.error:
            for message in to_send:
                your_socket.send(message)
```

Notice that this code will crash your program every time it reaches the timeout (that's just how the timeout is defined in the socket library), so you must have your code inside a try, except block.
Also, you will not miss any messages sent while in the except block, as the messages will wait for you on the network card so you can receive them at any time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I would like the to_send list triggered by the user's command-line input. If I use your_socket.send(input()) at the last line, the program will pause to wait for the user's input instead of keeping receiving messages. Is there any other way?

Comment: @JinpeiHan In your case, I think the easiest solution is to just have a thread for the input.